# Function that cannot be extended continuously out of sphere

Tags: real-analysis

Is there a continuous function $f:S^n \to \mathbb R$ such that $f$ *cannot* be extended to a continuous function on an (open) subset $U$ of $\mathbb R^{n+1}$ that contains $S^n$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Due to [Tietze extension theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tietze_extension_theorem), every continuous $f:S^n\to\mathbb{R}$ can be extended to a continuous function on $\mathbb{R}^{n+1}$.

Comment: Thanks. I wasn't actually interested in S^n itself but had in my mind a general compact subset hence I did not give much thought to the (obvious) solution above.

Comment: @Bernard: You are welcome!

Answer (score 0):

While there are general reasons, we can give an explicit formula for an everywhere continuous extension. Embedding the sphere as the unit sphere, we have

$$ f(\vec{v}) = \begin{cases}
||\vec{v}|| f(\hat{v}) & \vec{v} \neq 0
\\ 0 & \vec{v} = 0 \end{cases} $$